# How to iterate through a map in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some data samples stored in a variable `data_` as below.

```
[{'Age': 39, 'count': 5}, {'Age': 24, 'count': 5}]
```

So I have this javascript list as below:

```
 barChartData(data) {
    const datum = [
      {
        values: [
          {
            label: "A",
            value: -29.765957771107,
            color: "#3ebfea",
          },
        ],
      },
    ];

    return datum;
  }

// and use it
barChartData(data_) // passing the data sample to the function
```

And now what I want to do is, change the keys in the `datum` inside function with the `data_` I pass.

so it will look like this:

```
barChartData(data) {
    const datum = [
      {
        values: [
          {
            label: "Age",
            value: <Age-received-from-data-parameter>,
            color: "#3ebfea",
          },
        ],
      },
    ];

    return datum;
  }
```

How can I iterate/map the `data` inside the `barChartData` function and assign the value

I tried  but I it is not working and I am pretty sure something is missing.

Can someone help me do this?

This is I what I tried

```
barChartData(data) {
    const datum = [
      {
        // key: "Cumulative Return",
        values: [
          data.map((emp, index) => 
          
          { // below gives syntax errors
            label: "Age",
            value: emp.Age,
            color: "#3ebfea",
          }
          )
         
        ],
      },
    ];

    return datum;
  }
```

Comment: 1) data.map already returns an array, no need to wrap it into `[...]`; 2) if arrow function returns an object, it should be wrapped into `{}` once more

Comment: so how can I use it? Can you give a working example? I am new to reactjs

Answer (score 0):

First, `map` function already returns an array, and it seems there's no need to wrap it into `[]` once more. Second, when arrow function returns an object, it should be wrapped into `()` to avoid confusing the parser. So here's one way your function might look like:

```js
const source = [{
  'Age': 39,
  'count': 5
}, {
  'Age': 24,
  'count': 5
}];

// ----------------
function barChartData(data) {
  const datum = [{
    // key: "Cumulative Return",
    values: data.map(emp => ({ // note `(` wrapper
      label: "Age",
      value: emp.Age,
      color: "#3ebfea",
    }))
  }];
  return datum;
}

console.log(barChartData(source));
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be like `values: source.map((emp) => [
          {
            label: "Age",
            value: emp.Age,
            color: "#3ebfea",
          },
        ]),` ?

Comment: It's a function, so it should work with its parameter, not a global variable. As for mapper return format, it actually depends on what's expected of that function (probably by charting library).

Comment: I replaced this with my dataset but the `map` only iterates once

Comment: The count of map invocations is the same as the number of elements in the originating array - not more, not less. Have you checked the console output in the snippet?

Comment: Is there an online java compiler that I can share with you my code?

Comment: You mean something like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)? There's [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) too.

Comment: The problem is now graph (bar chart) shows values but they shows on top of each other. like stacked. not properly.

Comment: I found the reason why it is being stacked. In your example, you have given two keys, namely `Age` and `count`, and further I added three keys to that namely `label`, `value` and `color`. Apparently there should be keys matching those three